# C++: why isn't the destructor designed like delete of a pointer?

Tags: c++, destructor

If we delete a pointer for the first time, it release the memory and assign NULL to the pointer.
If we delete the pointer (with NULL value) for the second time, nothing happens, and no error throws out.

Then why isn't the destructor designed like delete of a pointer, 
We manuall call destructor of an object, and assign something to the object, like NULL.
so that destructor can be called for many times without error?

[Update] I meant we assign NULL explicitly to the pointer.

Comment: Deleting a second time? Undefined behaviour = Anything could happen. And if the destructor could be called multiple times without crashing is up to you, but irrelevant.

Comment: *“If we delete a pointer for the first time, it release the memory and assign NULL to the pointer.”* – This is not true.  `int * x = new int; delete x; delete x;` will invoke undefined behavior.  What `delete` does is *call* the destructor of the pointed to object and then deallocate its memory.

Comment: Invoking `delete` on a pointer **does not** assign NULL to it. And deleting a pointer a second time is **undefined behavior**, which might do nothing on some platforms but will often cause a **heap corruption**. And it wouldn't make any sense for the destructor to be able to be called twice, because you can only destroy something once. Once it's destroyed, it's destroyed, period, you can't destroy it again.

Comment: So what's  your question?

Comment: there is almost never a good case for manually calling destructor's, unless you are using placement new. use scope to control object lifetime, or use smart-pointers.

Comment: Is the question: Why, when one deletes a pointer, does it not automatically get set to NULL rather than leaving it to the programmer?

Comment: If you're asking why the language was designed the way it was, you're asking the wrong people in the wrong place. Unless Stroustrup or an ANSI committee member responds, all you can possibly get here is more or less uninformed opinion. -1

Comment: @EJP, yes, I am asking about design purpose. Now I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose of constructors and destructors is to avoid manual calling of the destructor. It's designed so that objects are automatically destroyed when no longer in use. This makes it harder for the programmer to accidentally forget to delete an object; or to use an object that has already been deleted.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am asking about design purpose.